# Designing complex relations tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, yii

I have some problems with database projecting.

I have some item types, let's say those are "news", "articles", "files", etc.

Also I have "categories" table to store categories for each type. Type is specified in special field "category_type". So there're defined constants in my application code: news = 0, articles = 1, files = 2, etc.

Now the question is - what will be the correct way to build connections tables?

One way: I can create several tables for each type - "news2categories", "articles2categories", "files2categories", etc.

And the second option is to build one global table, which will have 3 fields "item_id (int), item_type (int), category_id (int)". Well actually I already have one global table for categories with type division by one field only. But is it the right way? I don't want to spawn dozens of identical tables, but on the other hand relations with one table and multiple types are seem to be too abstract and complex. Please advise.

DB will be used by Yii framework mainly, if it makes any sense in solving this problem.

Comment: Can a same category be shared between items of different types? For example, can an article and a file belong to the same category?

Comment: use Table Inheritance. Make news, article, file subtypes of some supertype

Comment: Branko, I hope no, it can't be shared. And if such thing occurs, I see no problem in creating some _let's say identical_ categories.

Comment: Neil could you please explain your thought? How can this supertype help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between articles, news, and files?  Can a each of these have multiple categories (many-to-many)?  Assuming yes on the many-to-many need of multiple categories to each type (article, news, etc...) and that they are each sufficiently different from each other, I'd have the following tables:

```
 category
 news
 category_news
 article
 article_category
 file
 category_file
```

Each category linking table would have 2 columns: category_id and item_id (news_id, article_id, etc...)

I use the db coding standard of naming all db tables in the singular (feel free change to plural -ack- if Yii does otherwise) and having my linking tables the name of each linked table separated with an underscore (names in alphabetical order).

Whatever you do, be consistent.

Comment: Yes, each type can be in several categories. As @Mandar said earlier this scheme can give some troubles when it's time to add more types. Obviously this structure is easier to review and understand, but I just have some itching about creation lots of same tables.

Comment: @user475255 I agree, if the types are sufficiently similar and you expect to add more than an handful new types, go with a common 'item' table and specify type.  This is sort of the Drupal 'node' approach or how wordpress has morphed everthing into a 'post'. However, if you're not going to ever have more than 4-5 types and they don't share a base class on the code side, you should go with the separate tables for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

First way seems problematic since you might want your design to be flexible with adding / removing different types. If you add new type, you will have to add a new table, which I feel is not a good design.

How about this design.

Table : Category,
Columns :
CategoryID (PK) 
TypeID (FK to Types table.)

Table : Types, Columns: TypeID (PK), TypeValue

Store Types news, article, etc in Types table. This will make design more flexible with adding or removing types and categories.

Comment: Well yes I thought about this "types" table. But anyway I can't see any way I'm getting rid of hardcoding those types definitions in my application. That's why I just didn't create that table.